# What is the equivalent of gfortran flag mieee-fp on macOS Ventura (M2, GCC 12.2 Arm)?

Tags: gcc, floating-point, arm64, macos-ventura

I'm trying to compile a fortran model on macOS Ventura (macOS 13, M2 chip), with GCC 12.2 Arm (downloaded here https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases, and/or installed with homebrew)

It seems mieee-fp is not supported in this environment? Is there a flag equivalent to mieee-fp? Thank you!

`gfortran: error: unrecognized command-line option '-mieee-fp' configure:1992: $? = 1 configure:2030: result: no configure: failed program was: |       program main | |       end configure:2035: error: in $path: configure:2037: error: Fortran compiler cannot create executables See`config.log' for more details`

I also tried to install GCC 11.x.y but I don't think it is compatible with macOS Ventura.

Comment: This is a general GCC option, not a gfortran one. I do not think you can do much more than `-fno-unsafe-math-optimizations`, but I am not an expert.

Comment: It seems this is a legacy flag that can be removed, see discussion here: https://github.com/iains/gcc-12-branch/issues/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a legacy flag that can be removed; see the discussion here:
[github.com/iains/gcc-12-branch/issues/20](https://github.com/iains/gcc-12-branch/issues/20)